# xa assembler: 16 bit immediate operand

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to use `xa` to assemble some 65816 assembly, but it complains about "overflow errors" when it encounters 16 bit immediate operands, such as

```
bit #$100
```

This does not happen for arguments that fit in 1 byte, so it's clearly assuming an 8 bit accumulator rather than a 16 bit one. How can I indicate that the accumulator should be 16 bit? I am using the `-w` switch to enable 65816 opcodes, but that does not help. In `wla-dx` one can suffix the opcode with .w to explicitly tell it to use the 16 bit version of the opcode, but `xa` doesn't understand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more thorough read of the `xa` man page revealed these pseudo-ops:

```
.as: Makes A register  8 bit
.al: Makes A register 16 bit
.xs: Makes XY registers  8 bit
.xl: Makes XY registers 16 bit
```

So I solved the problem by inserting `.al : .xl` at the beginning of the file.